# Prevent wrapping of multiple logos in nav in bootstrap 4 xs size

Tags: navbar, nav, bootstrap-4

Most of the examples I found just hide everything except for the brand-logo and just show one toggle icon. But I want multiple icons on small screens but at the moment they wrap on xs size even if they have enough space.

I also replace the bigger icons by smaller icons now, but as it's not the missing space I guess, this does not help either.

The brand-logo and the two icons simply should be in the same line. Can someone please push me in the right direction. You have to run the code-snippet in an own window to make it small enough (problem is just on xs size).

```css
.material-icons.md-24 { font-size: 24px; }
.material-icons.md-48 { font-size: 48px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<header class="header">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-toggleable bg-faded justify-content-center">

    <!--Logo-->
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="/" title="logo">
      <span>logo-img</span>
    </a>

    <!--
    the centered links in the header (only visible on bigger screens)
    -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto justify-content-center hidden-sm-down">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">link1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">link2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- the icons on the right (xs screens)
    The two (and maybe more) icons SHOULD NOT WRAP
    -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto justify-content-end hidden-sm-up">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn">
          <i class="material-icons md-24" style="">mail_outline</i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn">
          <i class="material-icons md-24">favorite</i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- the icons on the right (bigger devices) -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto justify-content-end hidden-xs-down">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn">
          <i class="material-icons md-48" style="">mail_outline</i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn">
          <i class="material-icons md-48">favorite</i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flex-row` in the navbar and `navbar-nav` to prevent it from stacking vertically on `xs` screens..

https://www.codeply.com/go/beHGmETlkM

```
<header class="header">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-toggleable bg-faded justify-content-center flex-row">
    <!--Logo-->
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="/" title="logo">
      <span>logo-img</span>
    </a>
    <!--
    the centered links in the header (only visible on bigger screens)
    -->
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto justify-content-center hidden-sm-down">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">link1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">link2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- the icons on the right (xs screens)
    The two (and maybe more) icons SHOULD NOT WRAP
    -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto flex-row justify-content-end hidden-sm-up">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn">
          <i class="material-icons md-24" style="">mail_outline</i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn">
          <i class="material-icons md-24">favorite</i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- the icons on the right (bigger devices) -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto justify-content-end hidden-xs-down">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn">
          <i class="material-icons md-48" style="">mail_outline</i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn">
          <i class="material-icons md-48">favorite</i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/beHGmETlkM

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot! Why is it acting differently on xs? Or why is it not necessary on sm and above?

Comment: It's because the navbar is "mobile-first" so by default it's always stacked vertically on xs screens.